# Tkinter TopLevel window did not display it`s content

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm looking for a way to create a new Window by clicking the button with it's own wigets
I've written this code, but the new window's content did not dispay:

`Search` button click must fire the function that will create a new window with search row using `Entry` class from tkinter

ui.py:

```
class App(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.search_btn = tk.Button(self)
    self.search_btn["text"] = "Search"
    self.search_btn["command"] = self.on_search_button
    self.search_btn.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.grid(column=4, row=3, sticky="se")

def on_search_button(self):
    self.search_wnd = SearchWindow(self.master)


class SearchWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __int__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.query = tk.StringVar()
        self.search_row = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.query)
        self.search_row["justify"] = "left"
        self.search_row.pack()
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()
```

main.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
from ui import App

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. You are using a mix of methods to build your widgets. I would stick with one. 2. You use `self.pack()` in your `Toplevel` class... Toplevel doesn't use grid placements it is its own window so it doesn't need to be placed on the root window.

Comment: Yes, it's excess

Comment: lol. Took a mini but I found it. You have a typo in your `init` you are missing the `i` in `init` for your Toplevel class.

Comment: Yes, thank you. So stupid mistake XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your main problem is a typo.

Change:

```
class SearchWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __int__(self, master):
```

To:

```
class SearchWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
```

That said I would change a few things. You are over using `self.`. This is only needed when you need to make something a class attribute.

You also do not need to use any geometry managers on `Toplevel` as this is its own window.

Here is a cleaned up version of your example:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tk.Button(self, text="Search", command=SearchWindow).grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
        tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.destroy).grid(column=4, row=3, sticky="se")


class SearchWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.query = tk.StringVar(self)
        tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.query, justify='left').pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.master.destroy).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```